# force all domains https with www

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I tried 12 different solutions on this forum and non of them will work.
I want all my domains to have https://www.

Now i am using this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But now when i go to www.example.com it redirects to https://www.www.example.com 
(twice www.)

http://example.com works perfect it redirects to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a normal behaviour.
Actually, you'll need to check if `www` is in the host or not before doing a redirect.

An easy way would be to split the problem in two conditions

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# redirect http(s)://example.com to https://www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @JustinIurman the HTTPS example.com to HTTPS www.example.com redirect is missing no?

Comment: @Tom You're right. I've updated the code to take care of that. You only need to remove the https check for the second rule

Comment: @ficuscr : me too, did you got any solution?

Comment: @ShashankSaxena I'd say as of 2.4 this is obsolete.  Better see directives [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#Redirect) and [`FallbackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#FallbackResource).  HTTP Strict Transport Security is also worth a look.

Comment: This is not obsolete in 2.4 (proof here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html ). Maybe your framework (if any) is configured to force http or domain without www, which would explain the loop. Have a look at the network traffic to see what's happening there. However, I've seen that, on some servers, using `HTTPS` does not work (don't know exactly why) and using an alternative does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule to redirect to https://www

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: @vazzilly there was a slight typo, (missing % before {REQUEST_URI}) I have fixed it.